# Which functions use a given option?

Tags: functions, options, documentation, undocumented

I occasionally discover Options which look like they might be useful, if only I knew which functions used that option. Is there a resource that lists all the functions which use a given option? What is the best way to search for all functions which use a given option?

In my case today i'm looking for functions that use ProgressReporting, but the question stands generally.

I tried `` Select[Names["*`*"], MemberQ[Options[ToExpression[#]], ProgressReporting -> _] &] `` but that's way too much to trawl through.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`WolframLanguageData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframLanguageData.html) with the property `"SymbolsUsingAsOption"` for this:

```
WolframLanguageData["ProgressReporting", "SymbolsUsingAsOption"]
(* {BayesianMaximization,  
    BayesianMaximizationObject, 
    BayesianMinimization,  
    BayesianMinimizationObject,  
    ChatEvaluate,  
    FindSystemModelEquilibrium,  
    FunctionCompile,  
    ImageSynthesize,  
    LaunchKernels,  
    LLMExampleFunction,  
    LLMFunction,  
    LLMResourceFunction,  
    LLMSynthesize,  
    ParallelArray,  
    ParallelCombine,  
    ParallelDo,  
    Parallelize,  
    ParallelMap,  
    ParallelProduct,  
    ParallelSum,  
    ParallelTable,  
    PrimePi,  
    ReconstructionMesh,  
    SpeechRecognize,  
    SystemModel,  
    SystemModelCalibrate,  
    SystemModelLinearize,  
    SystemModelMeasurements,  
    SystemModelParametricSimulate,  
    SystemModelSimulate,  
    SystemModelSimulateSensitivity,  
    SystemModelUncertaintyPlot,  
    TestReport,  
    TextSummarize,  
    TrainImageContentDetector,  
    TrainTextContentDetector,  
    WaitAll} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

currently trying to look at a subset by first getting all the names in the System` context:

```
namepatterns = "System`" <> # <> "*" & /@ ToUpperCase@Alphabet[];
allnameswithoptions = Select[Names[#], optionslength] & /@ namepatterns;
```

but even just generating that list of names with at least one option is slow, took like a minute for just `` "System`A*" `` and `` "System`B*" `` and its still working on the rest of the alphabet, oh wait it just finished. there are 2130 names in that list.

ok, well, looks like `Select[#, MemberQ[Options[ToExpression[#]], ProgressReporting-> _] &] &/@allnameswithpatterns`
yields the following list:

- FindSystemModelEquilibrium
- FunctionCompile
- SystemModel
- SystemModelCalibrate
- SystemModelLinearize
- SystemModelMeasurements
- SystemModelParametricSimulate
- SystemModelSimulate
- SystemModelSimulateSensitivity
- SystemModelUncertaintyPlot
- TrainImageContentDetector
- TrainTextContentDetector

Comment: You probably want `KeyExistsQ[Options[ToExpression[#]], ProgressReporting] &`. Or check for both `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` option forms.